# QuickBlox Android - How to retrieve Users by tags and sort by createAt?

Tags: android, quickblox

I use quickblox android version 2.1.1. I can retrieve Users by tags. it work fine! But i want to retrieve Users by tags and sort by createAt. How can I do it?
Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2):

QuickBlox SDK allow you to retrieve list of QBUsers by some tags. QBUsers class extends QBEntity, which contains method getCreatedAt().

```
public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }
```

By comparing each QBUsers Date instance, which returns by method above, you could sort your QBUsers list by createdAt field.